# changing cell template property in Angular UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on `Angular UI grid` and I am trying to change the cell template property on button click but it is not affecting the `UI grid`.

Here is the punker and when I click on toggleDisplay name it is not getting changed.

check link:-

[plnkr.co/edit/Q0WcJC37bSGF7Huet39Q?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0WcJC37bSGF7Huet39Q?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0WcJC37bSGF7Huet39Q?p=preview

Comment: Please [edit] all the code into question.

Comment: check this link http://plnkr.co/edit/3maYb8g7Rfr8qEh0KKN4?p=preview

Comment: Unable to find out the `cell button` on your plunk ? Please remove all not working plunk and put working one on your original post. Otherwise every one will get confuse.